# dont understand this fork/exec type program. I dont get how B will be printed twice

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, fork, exec

Below is the code of the prog1 program. Assume that the execution of a program is successful unless a query explicitly states otherwise.
this is the code:

```
    int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
        int i;
        for(i=1;i<3;i++){
            if (fork()==0){
                printf("A");
                execvp("./prog2",&argv[1]);
                printf("B");
                exit(1);
            } 
            printf("C");
        
        }
        printf("D");
        return 0;
    }
```

We write the command ./prog1
How many times will each of the letters A,B,C,D be printed?

my thoughts are that: The (initial) process will fork into a parent and a child. The parent will print C, the child on the other hand will enter the if, print A and then the exec will be executed entering another program, so the print B that follows will never be printed. Similarly, this will happen in the second fork too. Parent prints C child does the same as before. At the end parent prints D.
So A two times, B zero times, C two times and D one time.
But what i get when running it is: A two times, B two times, C three times and D one time.
Can someone please explain?

corrected photo if execvp fails [correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDBFs.jpg)

Comment: *Assume that the execution of a program is successful* I wouldn't assume that if you're getting B printed out (Or does `./prog2` print it?). Add some error checking to see if `execvp()` worked or not.

Comment: Your `execvp` is failing because `./prog2` does not exist or is not executable, so you get the Bs in the output.

Comment: wow yeah thats true! do you know how do i get error checking for execvp()? if it is successful though i cannot comprehend how execvp() would lead into printing B. thanks for your time btw!

Comment: the question i have to answer considers that the execvp() does indeed suceed. Because later in the exercise it has a question saying consider that execvp() fails. So i guess my problem is that i am considering the output in my vscode as the correct one which probably has execvp() failing. if is that the case, if execvp() does indeed succeed is what im describing correct?

Answer (score 0):

It must be a problem with your execvp of ./prog2.
This can be demonstrated by changing the program to a well known program that will surely work:

```c
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
        int i;
        for(i=1;i<3;i++){
            if (fork()==0){
                printf("A");
                fflush(stdout);
                execvp("/bin/true",&argv[1]);
                printf("B");
                exit(1);
            } 
            printf("C");
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        printf("D");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot. one final question though. since printf("A"); is before it enters into the execvp() why is it not printed?(see my photo)

Comment: @MikeBalts "A" will be printed by the child process. So you should see "A" twice, one for each loop interaction that forked.

Comment: thats what i would expect as well but when running your program(sucession of execvp()) no A is printed. this is the output i get: CCD

Comment: @MikeBalts that i can't explain. when i run it, i do see CCDAA. The order might be jumbled and might appear elsewhere relative to the other output, but I definitely see the two "A"s.

Comment: @MikeBalts one more thought, try change "A" to a more recognisable word, e.g. "Apple". Maybe that will make it easier to see.

Comment: ok thats weird. hahaha. what libraries do you use?

Comment: @MikeBalts you mention "libraries" and it sounds horrible to me, so perhaps that means you are programming on something like Windows or some other platform like that, where /bin/true doesn't exist. I'm just using a standard Linux platform and i need no special libraries.

Comment: @MikeBalts Your "./prog2" (forward slash) that made me think you were using a Unix or Linux platform

Comment: haha. i use WSL: ubuntu on my vscode(windows 11) so i think its pretty much like linux. but i dont get the A or Apple.

Comment: Standard output to a terminal is buffered. Output printed without a final newline character is put into a buffer and not immediately printed. When the process forks, both the parent and the child have the pending output in their now-separate buffers and may print it eventually. When `execvp` executes successfully, it wipes away the prior program state, including pending output in the buffer.

Comment: but since execvp is inside the child process will it wipe away the prior buffer of the child or both child and parent? so what is the correct output(if it is successful)?

Comment: @MikeBalts Eric makes a good point, you can `fflush(stdout)` after each print to be certain it is not buffered. buffer will only be wiped on the child processes, i.e. the process that call execvp.

Comment: this is a past exam question. so i have to work with that code. this is not a code im trying to write/optimize.

Answer (score -1):

> But what i get when running it is: A two times, B two times, C three times and D one time. Can someone please explain?

In the below, all `printf` output is held in a buffer until stated otherwise.

The initial process spawns a child.

The child prints A, tries to execute `prog2` but fails, prints B, and exits. At exit, its buffered A and B are output.

The parent prints C, loops, and spawns another child. In this fork, the buffered C exists in both the parent and the child, since the fork copied the entire process. The child prints A and B as above and exits. At this exit, the buffered C, A, and B are printed.

The parent prints C (adding to the one already in its buffer), finishes the loop, prints D, and exits. At this exit, the buffered C, C, and D are printed.

The cumulative output of the above is ABCABCCD, although the order may vary.

Comment: ohh! so my mistake is not missing a C in the parent, its the fact that i dont consider the initially buffered C from the parent(first iteration) existing in both processes after the first iteration, hence to the(second) child(of the second fork) as well. could you check the edited photo which i corrected after your response so im 100% that i understood correctly?(much appreciated response.)